# Split CSV/XLSX file into multiple sheets based on column names using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a CSV file with almost 190 column exported from SQL data. Now I would like to split the single CSV\XLSX whichever support into multiple sheets based on specific column say,

```
       Sample.csv
       id  name  technology    User  Countries   Support_Place Support_Details
       1   A.aaa   "SQL,JAVA"  user1   US          US1           6766678 NAM
       2   B.bbb    Linux      user2   Japan       Japan2        9878678 RAN
       3   C.ccc     Java      user3    India      India3        6545654 CAN

      Expecting,

       Sample.csv
       sheet1
       ====
       id  name  technology    
       1   A.aaa   "SQL,JAVA"  
       2   B.bbb    Linux     
       3   C.ccc     Java   

        User Sheet2
       ==============
         User  Countries  
         user1   US    
         user2   Japan 
         user3    India

      Support_Place Sheet3
     =====================
         Support_Place Support_Contacts
           US1           6766678 NAM
          Japan2        9878678 RAN
          India3        6545654 CAN
```

Please let me know how to split the columns into separate sheets based on Column name.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest retrieving 3 different CSV files using SQL instead.

Comment: I suggest two separate steps: (1) Use a specialized CSV library to split up the source data - such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html), or others. (2) Use POI to create the sheets you need from the split data. Both of these steps probably already have questions (and answers) here on Stack Overflow, if you do some research. Give it a try, and if you get stuck, you can ask a specific question for a specific problem you encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may be useful to you if you don't have to use Apache POI. In fact, it is more efficient based on fastexcel.

```java
import cn.hutool.core.io.FileUtil;
import cn.hutool.core.text.csv.CsvReader;
import cn.hutool.core.text.csv.CsvUtil;
import cn.hutool.core.text.csv.CsvWriter;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Workbook;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Worksheet;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ExcelSplitTest {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelSplitTest.class);


    @Test
    public void Test1() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (CsvWriter writer = CsvUtil.getWriter("D:\\tmp\\TEST_1.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            writer.writeHeaderLine(IntStream.range(0, 50).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{}));
            for (int i = 0; i < 230000; i++) {
                String[] strings = new Random().ints(50, 100, 150).mapToObj(a -> "TEST_" + a).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{});
                writer.writeLine(strings);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }
    /**
     * convert by fastexcel
     */
    @Test
    public void Test3() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (OutputStream os = FileUtil.getOutputStream("D:\\tmp\\TEST_3.xlsx")) {
            Workbook wb = new Workbook(os, "MyApplication", "1.0");
            try (CsvReader csvReader = CsvUtil.getReader(FileUtil.getUtf8Reader("D:\\tmp\\TEST_1.csv"))) {
                Worksheet ws1 = wb.newWorksheet("Sheet 1");
                Worksheet ws2 = wb.newWorksheet("Sheet 2");
                csvReader.stream().forEach(a -> {
                    long originalLineNumber = a.getOriginalLineNumber();
                    int col1 = 0;
                    int col2 = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            ws1.value((int) originalLineNumber, col1, a.get(i));
                            col1++;
                        }
                        else{
                            ws2.value((int) originalLineNumber, col2, a.get(i));
                            col2++;
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            wb.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

}
```

Dependencys:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastexcel</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
    <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.16</version>
</dependency>
```